Orientation of Magnetic Induction of a Dipole Source in MEG
I am working with source-reconstructed MEG data, and what I would like to know is that
when we obtain the magnetic induction (using the right-hand thumb rule) of a dipole source, is it only the polarity of this source that affects the orientation of the magnetic induction or does the orientation of the dipole source also affect it?
Thank you!

What do you mean by "magnetic induction"? Are you simply referring to the magnetic field?

Yes. But I read in “Magnetoencephalography for brain electrophysiology and imaging” by Sylvain Baillet that people mostly confuse magnetic induction with magnetic field, so I didn’t want to use a term that might be inaccurate.
